# Plot a histogram with ggplot of mean of a variable in function of another varable's observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will give an simple example to illustrate my issue.

```
dura <- c(158, 21, 451, 157, 963, 485, 211, 154, 1454, 475)
tel <- c("nokia", "apple", "samsung", "lg", "samsung", "lg", 
         "apple", "motorola", "samsung", "huawei")
color <- c("blue", "orange", "white", "green", "black", "blue", 
          "yellow", "green", "red", NA)
df <- data.frame(dura, tel, color)
```

For example here, I want to have the mean of duration for eatch tel as histogram plot?
I don't know if I have to use the apply functions or ggplot do it directly?

```
t1 <- tapply(df$dura,df$tel, mean)
barplot(t1, horiz=F,main="DurÃ©e selon la marque de tÃ©lÃ©phone", 
        ylab = "DurÃ©e moyenne (ms)", cex.names = 0.6, las = 2, col =    "orange")
```

Is it possible with ggplot?

Comment: Please clarify. You want a barplot? A histogram is something different.

Comment: I want a barplot like mine but with ggplot function, is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This includes calculation of the mean in the ggplot2 code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = tel, y = dura)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", fill = "orange") +
  theme_bw()
```

Read ggplot2 tutorials to learn more about it.

Comment: just one more question, is-it possible to display the number of each "tel" manufacturer on bars ?

Comment: I have to use this argument "geom_text(aes(label = ))" but how can I count the number of tel by manufacturer ?